# Why split Unity Sprite Images into folders?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm a beginner of Unity.

I had a question while studying.

When add a Sprite image to the Assets,

Why do I add it under the Sprite folder under the Resources folder?

Without dividing the folder,

What's the difference between adding a Sprite image directly to an Assets and adding a Sprite image to Resources> Sprites?

For example, the picture below.

[image]

[image]

Unity As a beginner, I have a lot of questions.

I need your help.

I would really appreciate it if you could explain it easily.

Comment: I dont think there is a crucial difference. It is just the way you organize and how you work. It is a habbit. Also if you are working in a multi-people project that might help for everyone to find their need easly

Comment: There are many things to ask about Unity. Can you have 1:1 chat with me?

Comment: It is great that you have enthusiasm to learn Unity. But did you check tutorials? There should be hundreds of them almost about every subject, you can try to look up from there.

Comment: I refer to the tutorial. But there are too many areas to study, and there are many things that are not easy to understand. I often ask questions about things that are not easy to understand.

Comment: You can't learn everything in one day. It takes practice and time. If you want to be professional this time might be years. Ask yourself this; "What do you want to do with Unity?", if it is a game, "What kind of game do you want?", "How will be your game art?", "Singleplayer or multiplayer?". Make your plan. Start looking them one by one. Check how to move a cube with keyboard for example. After apply this technique to your character etc.

Comment: It's great advice to me.. thank you and I am practice that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two main reasons for that. First being the most obvious, organization! Even for small games you'll end up having hundreds to thousand different assets and **type of assets**. Like scripts, scenes, models, fonts, etc. If you put them all in the same folder you'll just lost you mind trying to retrieve what you need when you need it.

However, the path Resources>Sprites is not a hazard. The folder 'Resources' is part of a list of [Special Folders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html) and has a special effect (I let you read the short documentation).

#### From Documentation

> You can load Assets on-demand from a script instead of creating instances of Assets in a Scene for use in gameplay. You do this by placing the Assets in a folder called Resources. Load these Assets by using the Resources.Load function.
>
> You can have multiple Resources folders placed anywhere inside the Assets folder. Place the needed Asset files in a Resources folder or a subfolder within it. Always include the subfolder path in the path passed to the Resources.Load function if your Asset files are in subfolders.
>
> Note that if the Resources folder is an Editor subfolder, the Assets in it are loadable from Editor scripts but are stripped from builds.

But the folder 'Sprites' is up to you. You can name it as you desire.

Comment: Does the folder Resources have functionality?

Comment: Yes, there is a link in my answer

Comment: well, Sprtie Image as well as .. for example Animation folder was possible?

Comment: I understand that Resources(Special Folder) folder was I need Resource use at Runtime. it's Right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. You can place sprite immage whereever you want. It is just a way to organize items. While you will be working for a while in Unity, you will see why it's so important to organize items in folders. Resources also has special functionality it  is describet in @MrDos answer.